# RxJava flatMapIterable with a Single - Springboot

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm using `Single` to retrieve a list from database and since it is only supposed to return a single value I think is the option to go.

I'm having problems retrieving a single value Long from that list that I want to store in a variable.

```
Single<List<Currency>> currencyListOrigin = 
    currencyService.getCurrencyByCodeLike(request.getMonedaOrigen());
```

This is what I want to achieve, but changing this code to get the same result but with Single

```
Long codOriginCurrency = currencyListOrigin
                             .stream()
                             .findFirst()
                             .map(Currency::getId)
                             .orElse(null);
```

Comment: your question is not clear, can you add some detail pls ?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Single<Long>` is not a valid option here. You should use a `Maybe` as the return type can be empty (there is no null when we talk about reactive streams).

If you want to get the `id` of `Currency` as a `Maybe<Long>` type you should proceed with the following code:

```
private Maybe<Long> getCurrencyId() {
    return getCurrencyByCodeLike()
            .flatMapMaybe(currency -> currency.stream()
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(Currency::getId)
                    .map(Maybe::just)
                    .orElseGet(Maybe::empty)
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private Maybe<Long> getCurrencyId() {
    return currencyService
            .getCurrencyByCodeLike(request.getMonedaOrigen())
            .filter(new Predicate<List<String>>() {  
                @Override
                public boolean test(List<String> currencies) throws Exception {
                    return !currencies.isEmpty(); // Make sure the list has at least one element.
                }
            }) 
            .map(new Function<List<String>, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply(List<String> currencies) throws Exception {
                    return currencies.get(0).getId(); // Get the first element and return the id.
                }
            }) 
            .switchIfEmpty(Maybe.<Long>empty()); // If the list is empty, return Maybe.empty().
}
```

From what I understand, you want to return the currency id of the first element in the list of currencies, then the above code should do the job.

Also note that `RxJava2` onwards you cannot emit `null` in the stream. Instead we can use `Maybe` and emit `Maybe.empty()` when the list is empty.